# For BM $W$ starting at $x \in [0,a]$, the probability that $W$ hits $0$ before $a$

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

Let $T_b = \inf \{t \ge 0: W_t = b\}$ for brownian motion $W$ and $P^x$ will be a one-dimensional Brownian family.

Then we have 
[image]

Show that for $a>0, 0 \le x \le a:$ 
$$P^x[T_0 < T_a] = \frac{a-x}{a}, P^x[T_a < T_0] = \frac{x}{a}.$$

So to get the two probabilities, we just need to integrate the two infinite sums over $t$. However, I don't know how to evaluate the integrals for these sums.

Also, how can we use this to compute $E^x(T_0 \wedge T_a) = x(a-x), 0\le x \le a$?  I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: Do you have the restriction to solve this by integration over those denisties? There is a martingale approach which give you a much easier computation on this one.

Comment: @Falrach This question is given immediately after the identities I have attached above. Perhaps we can use the transform $E^x[e^{-\alpha(T_0 \wedge T_a)}]$ for this problem?

Comment: By the way, from which book is this image?

Comment: @Falrach Karatzas and Shreve's Brownian Motion and Stochastic Calculus

Comment: Ah, I knew this notation looks familiar.

Answer (score 1):

My idea would be the following (I have not checked it through, but you could try it at your own at first):

By dominated convergence we have
$$\Bbb P^x (T_0 < T_a) = \lim_{\alpha \to 0 }  \Bbb E[ e^{-\alpha T_0 \wedge T_a} 1_{T_0 < T_a}] = \lim_{\alpha \to 0} \frac{\sinh ((a-x)\sqrt{2\alpha})}{\sinh (a\sqrt{2\alpha})}$$
This limit should be computable (looks like l'Hospital). Note that $\Bbb P^x (T_a < T_0) = 1 - \Bbb P^x (T_0 < T_a)$.

Further we should have

$$\Bbb E [T_0 \wedge T_a ]= \lim_{\alpha \to 0} \Bbb E [T_0 \wedge T_a e^{-\alpha T_0 \wedge T_a}] = \lim_{\alpha \to 0} - \frac{\text d }{\text d \alpha} \Bbb E[ e^{-\alpha T_0 \wedge T_a}] = \lim_{\alpha \to 0} - \frac{\text d }{\text d \alpha} \frac{(x -\frac a 2)\sqrt{2\alpha}}{\cosh(\frac a 2 \sqrt{2\alpha})}$$

You could share the exact computations as own answer, if this works and you have figured it out.

By the way, here is the martingale argument:

$M_t = W_{t\wedge T_0 \wedge T_a} - W_0$ is a martingale, thus by dominated convergence
$$ x = \lim_{t\to \infty}\Bbb E^x [M_t] = \Bbb E^x [W_{T_0 \wedge T_a}] = a\Bbb P^x(T_a < T_0)$$